# Python requests for Google Book API. How to create url?

Tags: python-requests

I'm using this [`API`](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?) to search through books. I need to create a request with given `parameters`. When I use `requests` library and `params` argument it creates bad URL which gives me wrong response. Let's look at the examples:

```
import requests
params = {'q': "", 'inauthor': 'keyes', 'intitle': 'algernon'}
r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?', params=params)
print('URL', r.url)
```

The URL is https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=&inauthor=keyes&intitle=algernon

Which works but gives a different response than when the link is as [`Working Wolumes`](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#WorkingVolumes) tells.

Should be: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:keyes+intitle:algernon

Documentation of requests tells only about params and separates them with `&`.
I'm looking for a library or any solution. Hopefully, I don't have to create them using e.g. f-strings

Comment: I don't know if it will make a difference, but you would not normally put the question mark at the end of the URL. `get` will put it there for you when you pass in params.

Comment: I doesn't make any difference. The `URI` looks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a parameter to send the url, the way you are doing it now is not what you wanted.

In this code you are saying that you need to send 3 query parameters, but that is not what you wanted. You actually want to send 1 parameter with a value.

```
import requests
params = {'q': "", 'inauthor': 'keyes', 'intitle': 'algernon'}
r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?', params=params)
print('URL', r.url)
```

try below code instead which is doing what you require:

```
import requests
params = {'inauthor': 'keyes', 'intitle': 'algernon'}
new_params = 'q='
new_params += '+'.join('{}:{}'.format(key, value) for key, value in params.items())

print(new_params)

r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?', params=new_params)
print('URL', r.url)
```